time traveling magician
I am looking for a manga where the MC is sent 1000 years or so into the future to stop a disaster from happening. The first thing he does when he awakens is to retrieve his master's wand from some ruins. There, he meets a young girl who accuses him of stealing the "holy sword" from her after she had to beat the dungeon to get it. They get attacked, and he kills the monster. After that, he joins a school for holy sword users as a mage. The principal looks like his old female master, and after the duels to join the school, he challenges her to fight, but she refuses and tells him he needs to qualify himself.  Also his special magic is to cut anything, even space and time.

It's not ...

Seiken Gakuin no Makentsukai (or)
Nana Seiken to Maken no Hime (or)
Jujutsu Kaisen

... although it's very similar to the first two.

You could improve this question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Somebody on another platform told me the answer it was The Last Sage of the Imperial Sword Academy (AKA Kentei Gakuin no Magan Kenja).

Ten years after a cataclysm destroyed the planet, magic prodigy Lag
Logline is entrusted with the title of "sage" and the task of
preventing the world's destruction one thousand years from now.
However when he awakens from his time freezing spell the world he
finds is nothing like he remembers. Upon meeting a swordswoman named
Clau, Lag finds out that this world one thousand years in the future
doesn't know what magic is. After having his own magic mistaken for
swordsmanship, Lag enrolls in the Imperial Sword Academy in order to
unravel the mysteries of the world around him and fulfill his promise
to save humanity.


You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. As a self-answer, you won't be able to do it for 48 hours from the time the question was asked, but we hope you'll come back to do so.
